# Is their a best practice to creating multiple applications using node and nginx as a proxy server?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have nginx running as a proxy server along with a couple of node.js applications.  I have nginx port forwarding to each app in distinct ports.  I have one main server file that looks like this in sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Each app is running the following code in the /var/www/html directory with a port variable assigned to the above ports respectively:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Under Construction\n');
}).listen(port, '127.0.01');
```

This file doesn't look maintainable if you have a large amount of applications.  What are some other ways to develop this?

Comment: You would typically use a framework like Express for your web server that makes it easy to define routes for that server.  Then, each server defines it's own routes and nginx does not have to be involved in the sub routes that each web server is configured to handle.  So, in your specific example, you'd define a route in your web server for `/app2/aboutus` in your port 5000 server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I get the express routing part, but what do I put in the proxy script?  Do I put some type of wildcard like * at the end of the url in the location directive for each app like this: <root domain>/<appname>/* ?

Answer (score 1):

I use express to listen to the ports I need without ever having to use nginx.

```
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on port ', port);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is best practice, but this has abstracted the routing from nginx to express like @jfriend00 suggested.